# Proof for reverse triangle inequality $|x - y| \ge |x| - |y|$.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Only step by step hint leading to the final proof.

How should I take it from here?

Comment: try adding $|y|$ to both sides.

Comment: This gives me $$|x| \leq |x-y|+|y|$$

Comment: @user Which is the straight-up triangular inequality.

Comment: But suppose the reader is unaware of the final conclusion, how should he begin the proof?

Comment: Can I ascertain that this proof is nothing but algebraic manipulation?
I had wanted to know the motivation behind the way the proof was laid out in the outset.

Answer (score 3):

You could divide this up into a lot of cases, and then show it for each case. Why are you forming the cases for $x-y$? Shouldn't you do for $x-y$?

**Case 1:** $x-y\geq0$

a) $x\geq y\geq0$

b) $x\geq0\geq y$

c) $0\geq x\geq y$

Similarly for **Case 2:** $x-y<0$